# axios response format object vs array

Tags: javascript, arrays, axios

I'm using axios/vue to fetch some data, and currently some of these calls are set manually.
I need to automate all of that, I'm almost successful but the data im getting is not correct.

Here is my current 'manual' setup:

```
let linksArr = ['abc.json','def.json'];
axios
    .all(linksArr.map(l => axios.get(l)))
    .then(
      axios.spread(function(abc, def) {
        var merged = [...abc.data, ...def.data]
      })
    )
```

And i'm getting a response like this with this setup:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {}
1: {}
```

But when I change it to something more 'automatic' like this (the linksArr is dynamic and can be very long):

```
let linksArr = ['abc.json','def.json'];
axios
   .all(linksArr.map(l => axios.get(l)))
   .then(
     responses => {
       var merged = [].concat(responses.map(res => res.data));
     }
   );
```

Im getting this as a response (notice the [{}]):

```
(2) [Array(1), Array(1)]
0: [{…}]
1: [{…}]
```

I would like to keep the same format for responses (object vs array) but I can not figure out how to do that...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your callback in the latter example. What you are doing in your original code is concatenating spread items (`...ARG.data`), whereas in your latter code you're missing this part. Please, check following, working example:

```
let linksArr = ['abc.json','def.json'];
axios
   .all(linksArr.map(l => axios.get(l)))
   .then(responses => {
     const merged = responses
      .map(r => r.data)
      .reduce((acc, item) => [...acc, ...item], []);
   });
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/j25l1n7835

Comment: Still does not give me the same response .. here are the differences
(2) [{…}, {…}]
vs
(2) [Array(1), Array(1)]

Comment: could you please create a sandbox for that? like jsbin or jsfiddle or codesandbox

Comment: Sure, compare the two jsfiddle and see the responses difference:
https://codesandbox.io/s/v6nrjorr37 and https://codesandbox.io/s/8q6x0lnp8

Comment: now I finally see. In your approach you're getting same data, however you're doing  `...app.data` which spreads an array into new one. Please, check my updated code

Comment: Dude you freakin saved my day. I spent countless hours on this... still I would like to know why I had to do a .map and a .reduce, I'm not sure why?

Comment: Well you don't have to, you can do it as Eugene Tsakh suggested. I just think this way it looks better: first you map, then you join - easier to get one's head around while reading

Answer (score 0):

Just add a spread operator for mapped responses: `[].concat(...responses.map(res => res.data));`